# HTML: How to unbold TH without CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: html, email

I am currently building an HTML e-mail with no CSS or JavaScript.  In Android 4.4.2, the TD stacking method doesn't work in either case, so I must replace TD tags with TH tags in order for it to work.  The only problem I have now is: how to unbold the `<TH>` tags without using any CSS or JavaScript?

TH tags are centered and bold by default.

Comment: _“TH tags are centered and bold by default”_ – and that is the result of: CSS. If not of the mail client showing the mail, then of the default stylesheet browsers apply. If you want to do something about that, you _have_ to use CSS, to overwrite those default formattings. // _Why_ do you not want to use CSS?

Comment: In one word NOT POSSIBLE without CSS and JS

Comment: If the TD stacking method doesn't work, why would replacing TDs by THs solve anything? Can you post an example of something that works using THs, but not using TDs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure inline styling works well for HTML emails.

```
<th style="font-weight:400;"></th>
```

Comment: @DanielPurPur ahh very true.

Comment: Wish there was something like `<unbold>`. For example, for use in GitHub markdown, where CSS styles are not allowed.